# Decouple differential equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, differential-equations

I have a system of two Second Order differential equations
$$r^2\ddot{r}−r^3(\dot{\varphi}^2+ω^2)=−GM$$
$$r \ddot{\varphi}+2 \dot{r}(\dot{\varphi}+\omega)=0 $$
using the conserved quantity $(\dot{\varphi}+\omega)r^2$, call it *Ω*.
I have shown that it is indeed a conserved quantity, as its time-derivative is $r$ times the second equation and therefore zero. However, I don't know how this is supposed to help me decouple the two equations.
I would be very thankful for hints.

Comment: is \omega a function or a constant?

Comment: Hint: $\dot{\varphi}=-\omega +\Omega/r^2$ may be substituted in the first equation, which is now a one variable one.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for your math question?

Answer (score 2):

Since $h:=r^2(\dot{\varphi}+\omega)$ is conserved, $\frac{d}{dt}=(\frac{h}{r^2}-\omega)\frac{d}{d\varphi}$ and $\dot{r}=-h\frac{du}{d\varphi}$ with $u:=\frac{1}{r}+\frac{\omega r}{h}$ so $\ddot{r}=-h(\frac{h}{r^2}-\omega)\frac{d^2 u}{d\varphi^2}$. You'll want to rewrite your equations of motion in the coordinate system $(u,\,\varphi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that $\omega$ is a constant, I'd suggest you use that $\dot \phi + \omega = \alpha/r^2$ (from your conservation law with $\alpha$ some constant), insert this into the second equation, solve for $\ddot \phi$, integrate once (leaving aside constants it looks like something proportional to $1/r^2$ plus an integration constant) and insert this into the first equation, which then depends only on $r$.

Comment: The conservation of $r^2(\dot\varphi+\omega)$ derives from the second equation, it does not make sense to plug it back there. Rather, you should plug it into the first.

Comment: Sorry, it had not been clear to me that the 2nd equation had already been used.